# Add Service to Symfony Bundle

Tags: symfony, service

I'm trying to add a service to a new bundle i have just created.

I'm going to explain:

I have a form to create an administration module and after having submit the form; I have that instruction:

```
$service= $this->container->get("module." . $moduleTypeService);
```

But that instruction crash and I got error 500.

When i check my appDevDebugProjectContainer.php i can't see the the service name as you can see below, so I guess it's normal to get error 500.

I ask for moduleTouring...so i guess i should be able to see module.touring

```
'module.page' => 'getModule_PageService',
        'module.shoppereval' => 'getModule_ShopperevalService',
        'module.user' => 'getModule_UserService',
        'monolog.handler.console' => 'getMonolog_Handler_ConsoleService',
```

I really don't know what's wrong.

Here is my service.yml

```
services:
    module.touring:
        class: Ups\TouringBundle\Services\ModuleTouringService
        calls:
            - [ setContainer,[ @service_container ] ]
```

Thanks for your help, I'm a little bit lost right now.

Comment: Do you have loaded the `service.yml` into the bundle DI extension? or imported it in your main `services.yml`?

Comment: Inside my DependencyInjection folder i have the UpsTouringExtension and the configuration files. SO i think it should be loaded.

Comment: It shouldn't automatically.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/extension.html#using-the-load-method